# linter setting to ensure numeric arguments have explicit names?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, clang-tidy

Is there a linter setting, preferably for clang-tidy, that identifies or pessimizes the use of direct numeric arguments.

Identify the following as bad

```
socket(0, 0, 0)
```

Identify the following as good

```
int domain = 0; int type = 0; int protocol = 0;
socket(domain, type, protocol)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a check named [readability-magic-numbers](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-magic-numbers.html) intended for just this purpose.

There is a catch however that would prevent it from identifying your specific case:

> Since values 0 and 0.0 are so common as the base counter of loops, or initialization values for sums, they are always accepted without warning, even if not present in the respective ignored values list.

I suspect rewriting the check to identify `0` values would be simple enough if you really need it to work that way.